# Detect anything from a serial port

Tags: serial-port, pyserial

I have an undocumented button with an RS232 cable.
In pyserial I created a default port:

```
port = serial.Serial("/dev/ttyUSB0", timeout=0)
```

I am pretty sure that the button sends a signal everytime I push it(because of the previous behaviour).

When I push it a first time, port.read(1) returns b'' which is equal to nothing has been received yet. Then, when I push it a second time, I read b'\x00'. I suppose that my parameter(from the serial port(baudrate, paritybits, stopbits etc.) are wrong. Or could something else explain this behaviour? Is there a way to find out the correct parameters?

I do not have an oscilloscope

Comment: An RS232 button? Are you sure you're not supposed to be using the GPIO pins?

Comment: Well the button is not the only function of the hardware, there are more. But before, the button had an impact on the program on the pc on every push.

Comment: In the end I figured it out: they did not use a clear text protocol, but used the rts/cts and dtr/dts signals for communication..(just 4 states) took me long enought to figure that out. Maybe this will help someone to be more creative than me one day.. ;)